# Global time and globle date converting in php

Tags: php

in my web application, user has to enter a time and select a date.so i want to save that time and date in globle time and date.when it get it should appear in user's country time.so simply the requirement is to convert a string into globl time and globle date when saving and globle time and date convert into a string when retrieving.so please let me know if someone know the PHP functions for this.thank you!!!

Comment: And by global time you mean UTC? Also, your question needs some tidying.

Comment: Don't you want to use javascript, and take clients computer time?

Comment: yeh Tiberiu-Ionuț Stan, i mean UTC time.i was needed to convert string into date or time in UTC format.that was solved with date('c',$timestamp); in php

Comment: yes Mantas Vaitkūnas, i have to use client's machine time and client's time zone as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP dates and times always work on server side.

Did you already consider to use the timestamp and the **date_default_timezone_set()** function to get the "global" datetime?

```
php > echo time();
1344236016
php > $timestamp=1344236016;
php > echo date('c',$timestamp);
2012-08-06T08:53:36+02:00
php > date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
php > echo date('c',$timestamp);
2012-08-06T06:53:36+00:00
```

Comment: hi matteomattei.thanks that is the answer i want.the code works well.my problem solved by this code.thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Use `timezone_identifiers_list()` to get a list of timezones, then ask the use which one they are in.

Then use `date_default_timezone_set()` with the string you got from the previous function.